# How to upload file to Artifactory with matching wildcard

Tags: artifactory

I have a CLI like below

> jfrog.exe rt upload "*.exe;*.dll;*.bpl;"
> "apex/nightly/v7/v7.8.2/build/" --user=XX --password=XX --url=XX
> --recursive=false --flat=true

but returns success:0 and failure:0. This used to work when I uploaded `*.*`, but now I want to match these three patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command works while using with single argument of any pattern:

```
jfrog.exe rt upload "*.exe" "apex/nightly/v7/v7.8.2/build/" --user=XX --password=XX --url=XX --recursive=false --flat=true
```

Since you would like to match multiple patterns, we can use the --spec arguments, refer to article [jfrog-cli/uploading-files](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/uploading-files) for more detail.

Below is an example command and the payload sec format

```
jfrog.exe rt upload --spec upload-test.spec --user=XX --password=XX --url=XX --recursive=false --flat=true
```

% cat upload-test.spec

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "*.exe",
      "target": "apex/nightly/v7/v7.8.2/build/"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "*.dll",
      "target": "apex/nightly/v7/v7.8.2/build/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also, we can use simple pattern as `"pattern": "(*.exe|*.dll)"` which works as similar to above payload.